# no space between 'pages' and 'doi' fields when using the elsarticle-num bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, elsarticle, doi

I would like to ask how can I correct the `doi` entry format in the reference list? I am using `elsarticle-num` bibliography style. But I am getting the journal page number merged (without space and comma) with the doi entry in the final output.

[image]

I would like to have it like `.... 1-5, http://doi_link_here`.

PS. I downloaded the reference from google scholar and manually entered the doi in the bibtex file before compiling in latex. In the example I have shown a dummy reference.

```
@Article{checkme2020,
  author    = {Author Name},
  title     = {Title goes here},
  journal   = {Journal Name},
  year      = {2020},
  pages     = {1-5},
  doi       = {https://doi.org/123456/78901},
  publisher = {Publisher Name here},
}
```

Comment: Please post the full bib entry in question.

Comment: I have edited the post with full bib entry

Comment: The `elsarticle-num` bib style appears to expect non-empty `volume` and/or `number` fields for entries of type `@article`. More specifically, the odd behavior you've discovered goes away if either the `volume` or the `number` field (or, better still, both fields together) are non-empty. Would it be impossibly hard to find the applicable values for the `volume` and `number` fields?

Comment: Thank you! It has solved the problem.