# references bib not showing date

Tags: bibliographies

I have this overleaf document https://www.overleaf.com/9383883839kbstqwwxvjdc
where reference number 1 has a date but reference number 2 does not. I don't understand there is no error. Is there a command like `\bib_show_date=True` ?

You can also download the overleaf template from https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/elsevier

```
@Article{Einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
} 

@article{ps,
    author  = "Wenzhe Shi and Jose Caballero and Ferenc Huszár and Johannes Totz and Andrew P. Aitken and Rob Bishop and Daniel Rueckert and Zehan Wang",
    title   = "Real-Time Single Image and Video Super-Resolution Using an Efficient Sub-Pixel Convolutional Neural Network",
    year    = "2016",
    journal = "CVPR"
}
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: @Mico I use this function from the default code \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's inappropriate to use the `@article` entry type for the second item in your short bib file: The `@article` entry type should be used exclusively for pieces published in scholarly journals. According to the CVPR website, the correct entry type for the second item is actually `@incollection`, as the piece was published in a conference proceedings volume. The website provides the following suggested bibtex entry:

```
@inproceedings{Shi_2016_CVPR,
author = {Shi, Wenzhe and Caballero, Jose and Huszár, Ferenc and Totz, Johannes 
          and Aitken, Andrew P. and Bishop, Rob and Rueckert, Daniel      
          and Wang, Zehan},
title  = {Real-Time Single Image and Video Super-Resolution Using an 
          Efficient Sub-Pixel Convolutional Neural Network},
booktitle = {The IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)},
month  =  {June},
year   = {2016}
}
```

You're obviously free to change the key `Shi_2016_CVPR` to something else.

Of course, you're also free to cite some initial or preliminary version of the paper, in which you should be using either the `@techreport` or the `@misc` entry type.

A separate comment: The `elarticle-num` bibliography style is known to produce unreliable output for entries of type `@article` which are missing both the `volume` and the `number` field (as well as, in your case, the `pages` field). For another manifestation of this issue, see the posting [no space between 'pages' and 'doi' fields when using the elsarticle-num bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527464/5001). That's the cause of the missing `year` field issue. The solution in the present case, is *not* to try to "backfill" the "missing" `volume` and `number` fields. Instead, as noted earlier, the proper solution is to switch to a different entry type, say, `@incollection`.

Comment: Thank you very much !